# Ресайзинг иконок в адаптивном дизайне

Tags: css3, media-queries, responsive

Здравствуйте, интересно знать, как лучше сделать. Есть адаптивный сайт, иконки сайта находятся в спрайте, при разных разрешениях экрана иконки ресайзятся, так вот, как лучше поступить с ресайзом, есть варианты: использовать `transform: scale()`, запихнуть каждую иконку в отдельную картинку или же вовсе разные спрайты делать (как по мне, это худший вариант)?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно идеальный вариант - использовать svg для иконок.
А в случае со спрайтом для bg иконки ставится background-size: auto 100%; и размер регулируется высотой родительского блока (ширина его подгоняется пропорционально).